# onNextStep is not a function, functional components

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have a parent component with the state which is number, and I'm passing state to RegistrationForm component and `setActiveForm` to StepperComponent. In the stepper Component, there is a button on which click it should change state. But I'm getting 'onNextStep is not a function'

Parent component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Box, Divider, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import Logo from 'components/navigation/Logo'
import Footer from 'components/footer/Footer'
import RegistrationForm from 'components/forms/RegistrationForm'
import StepperComponent from 'components/stepper/StepperComponent'
import Section from 'components/section/Section'
import { SubTitle, Title } from 'components/UI'
import SuccessRegistration from 'components/forms/SuccessRegistration'

const RegisterPage = () => {
    const [activeForm, setActiveForm] = useState<number>(0)
    return (
        <>
            <Box maxWidth="1450px" px={['16px', '43px', '83px']} mx="auto">
                <Logo />
            </Box>
            <Section pt="23px">
                <Box maxWidth="580px" ml={['0', '0', '200px']} mb="25px">
                    <Title value="React Week 2021- Event Registraton Form" mb="8px" />
                    <SubTitle
                        value="React Week talks, classes and workshops will feature advanced topics aimed for junior and medior software developers, and consultants."
                        fontSize="16px"
                    />
                </Box>
                <Divider d={['none', 'none', 'none', 'block', 'block']} />
                <Flex flexDirection={['column', 'column', 'row', 'row']}>
                    <StepperComponent onNextStep={setActiveForm} />
                    <Box>
                        <Divider orientation="vertical" d={['none', 'none', 'none', 'block', 'block']} />
                    </Box>

                    <RegistrationForm activeForm={activeForm} />
                </Flex>
            </Section>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}

export default RegisterPage
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

RegistrationForm component:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Box } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import PersonalInfoForm from './PersonalInfoForm'
import TicketOptionForm from './TicketOptionForm'
import AdditionalInfoForm from './AdditionalInfoForm'
import FormContainer from './FormContainer'
import SuccessRegistration from './SuccessRegistration'

interface Props {
    activeForm: number
}

const RegistrationForm = ({ activeForm }: Props) => {
    const forms = [<PersonalInfoForm />, <TicketOptionForm />, <AdditionalInfoForm />]
    return <FormContainer>{forms[activeForm]}</FormContainer>
}

export default RegistrationForm
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Stepper component:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Box, Button } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { Step, Steps, useSteps } from 'chakra-ui-steps'

interface Props {
    onNextStep: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
}

const steps = [
    {
        label: 'Step 1',
        description: 'Personal Info',
    },
    {
        label: 'Step 2',
        description: 'Ticket Options',
    },
    {
        label: 'Step 3',
        description: 'Additional Info',
    },
]

const StepperComponent = ({ onNextStep }: Props) => {
    const { nextStep, prevStep, reset, activeStep } = useSteps({
        initialStep: 0,
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        onNextStep(activeStep)
    }, [activeStep])

    return (
        <Box w={['100%', '200px']} mt={['12px', '43px']}>
            <Steps activeStep={activeStep} orientation="vertical" colorScheme="blue" textAlign="center">
                {steps.map(({ label, description }) => (
                    <Step label={label} description={description} key={label}></Step>
                ))}
            </Steps>
            <Button onClick={nextStep}>NextStep</Button>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default StepperComponent
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```